# Modified Quicksort*

Tags: time-complexity, quicksort

given array of size n, and a function called FindPivot which returns the median with a time complexity of O(n^(1.1)).
what is the worst case time complexity of quicksort using the given func to find pivot?

the answer given by the teacher is theta(n^(1.1))
I thought it should be theta(n^1.1logn)
please explain

Comment: Can you justify your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the function returns the median, the time complexity of (this version of) Quicksort is described by the recurrence equation:
$$
T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n^{1.1}).
$$

By the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), this has solution $T(n) = O(n^{1.1})$.

It is not possible to conclude that $T(n) = \Theta(n^{1.1})$ from the given information since, e.g., FindPivot might run in time $\Theta(n)$ (recall that $\Theta(n) \subset O(n^{1.1})$), in which case the resulting complexity would be $\Theta(n \log n)$.

If we further assume that FindPivot runs in time $\Theta(n^{1.1}$) then the recurrence equation becomes $T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + \Theta(n^{1.1})$, which has solution $T(n) = \Theta(n^{1.1})$.

Comment: thank you! that helped

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, many small components of equal size in a recursion formula often result in a log n factor, which is smaller than any power.

In your case, your recursion has 2 * T(n/2) ≈ T(n) * 2 / 2^1.1 = T(n) / 2 ^1.1. Now the smaller components in your recursion shrink like a geometric series. You are not adding up items of equal size, so there is no factor log n.

Note that if we just compare n^1.1 and n ln n, the first one is larger from n = 5,000,000,000,000,000 and then quickly gets a lot faster.